# How to define layer order in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers

I added some geojson layers on my map but they are ordred in the menu randomly.
[image]

for example I like Zones to be above Bus line how to control this.
[here my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BiNfU83Xyhyz9qy7nIvb?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently solved this by working with Panes in Leaflet.js

http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

I can use this with any type of layer that I add to a Leaflet.js map. Very handy!

Comment: Please show me how in my plunker example because I still not making it.

Comment: I am using Leaflet 0.7.5 wich does not have panes function.